# AWS Step Function manual approval process

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am working on the requirement where the data entered in the form needs to be validated manually and once validated , a approval mail be be sent out and then data will be stored in the database.I plan to use AWS step function for this with token.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-serverless-manual-approval-steps-in-aws-step-functions-and-amazon-api-gateway/

I plan to use a similar design like in the link above.However is there a way not to use API Gateway for sending back the task token to step function to resume processing.Did anybody worked on the similar requirement and how the functionality was achieved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Step function can be invoked by the AWS Lambda function as well.
Once the form is validated and stored in database, you can trigger the Lambda function based on the database events(ex- if DynamoDB used then based on the DynamDB streams), and the lambda can start the step function.